# Fatal Error in Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I'm working with `magento 1.7.I` m getting the following **`fatal error`** on some products while adding product to cart .

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object 
in app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item.php 
on line 266
```

Kindly help and suggest ways to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restore the backup and check. That should work.